# Calling Asynchronous web api method in synchoronous method thrwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I am calling an asynchronous Web api from C# ASP.Net web application from synchronous method. I get error. 
one or more errors occurred. An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

If I call the same asynchronous web api from windows forms application using asynchronous method the web api return perfect value. I have to use synchronous method in Web Application and hence the code which is successfully tested in Windows application cannot be used in web application.
Below is the portion of code.

```
    private string SECURE_API_Async(string WebApiURL, HttpContent httpContent, string[] apiNames, HTTP httpMethod, DictionaryEntry[] apiValues)
    {
        try
        {
            using (httpContent)
            {

                Last_HTTPRequestContent = httpContent == null ? "null" :  httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiURL);

                if (SessionTokenID != null)
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SessionTokenID", SessionTokenID);
                }

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                string target_URI = "api";

                foreach (string apiName in apiNames)
                {
                    target_URI = string.Format("{0}/{1}",
                        target_URI,
                        apiName);
                }

                string target_URI_parameters = string.Empty;

                if (apiValues != null)
                {
                    target_URI_parameters = CreateParameterString(apiValues);
                }
                target_URI = (target_URI_parameters == string.Empty) ? target_URI : string.Format("{0}?{1}", target_URI, target_URI_parameters);

                _lastURL = httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString() + target_URI;
                Last_HTTPstatus = 0;
                Last_ReasonPhrase = string.Empty;
                Last_HTTPResponse = null;
                Last_HTTPResponseString = string.Empty;

                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                try
                {
                    switch (httpMethod)
                    {
                        case HTTP.PUT:
                            {
                                response = httpClient.PutAsync(target_URI, httpContent).Result;
                                break;
                            }
```

I get error when PutAsync method is called.

Now if I change the method to

```
private **async** **Task<string>** SECURE_API_Async(string WebApiURL,       HttpContent httpContent, string[] apiNames, HTTP httpMethod, DictionaryEntry[] apiValues)
```

and API call to

```
response = **await** httpClient.PutAsync(target_URI, httpContent);
```

I get the correct response.
What I learnt after searching the net is both

```
response = **await** httpClient.PutAsync(target_URI, httpContent);
```

(when the calling method has async keyword meaning calling method is aynchronous) and

```
response = httpClient.PutAsync(target_URI, httpContent).**Result**;
```

(when the method don't have async keyword meaning calling method is synchronous)

Should return correct response message.
But my synchronous method throws underlying connection error.
Can somebody help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing wrong credentials. So I was getting error An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Strange error. One of the headaches if you work in MS technology. They just don't throw proper error out. The correct error out should have been user credentials are wrong.

But the thing is you can call Asynchronous method if you use Result
for e.g.

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PutAsync(target_URI, httpContent).Result;//Synchronous call from Synchronous method

AND

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(target_URI, httpContent);//Synchronous call from ASynchronous method which has async keyword prefixed

gives the same result.